# External Links not working

Tags: 7, navigation

Tried both modules [External Links](https://drupal.org/project/extlink)  and [External New Tab](https://drupal.org/project/external)  none of my external URL leading links opens in a new tab, what could be causing this? I tried disabling jquery update, didn't help.

If you set option on extlink to add icon to every external link, it does it well, so it means it detects the external links, but when clicked it opens in same tab/page. Tested various browsers.

Comment: If it works on other browsers, it's a bug in a browser, or incompatibility that should be reported in module's issue queue. Always test client-side problems on at least 3 different browsers before proceeding further.

Comment: Tested on Chrome, same.

Comment: Could it do something with the server maybe? Or that the current website URL is raw IP, not domain?

Comment: Shouldn't be the case, as far as I know both are implemented mainly in JS. But their maintainers should know best - consider filling bugreport or feature request in their issue queues.